# Switching the Clef Positions

Tags: piano, sheet-music, midi, clefs

Ok, so, basically, I wanted to play this song called Heaven's Lullaby by BigRicePiano on YouTube. The issue was that he had no tutorial. Thankfully, someone named LightPiano made a Synthesia tutorial along with the MIDI file. But, the issue is that the MIDI file, when converted to a PDF through things like Musescore and other MIDI to PDF File Converters, the clef positions are always switched up and it throws me off a lot.

I could just do it reversed, but, if possible, I would REALLY want the clef positions to be normal. There is an image showing what I am talking about in the Musescore 2 application. If someone could help me, that would be great.[The clefs being switched up, this is all the way through the song too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNq8d.png)

Comment: it looks as these musescore midis and pdf are suboptimal, I think there are still other problems than the clefs: rhythm, notelength and key signs! compare this pdf version of the song:https://musescore.com/user/46224/scores/287776

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MuseScore, click 'Show MIDI import'.

[image]

You'll see that the Left Hand piano stave is above the Right Hand one.

Select it, click the down arrow, click Apply.

[image]

The RH and LH staves will now be the right way round.

[image]

Or do it in the Instruments page.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the Musescore edit view just press "i" to open the "Instruments" dialog. Then you can rearrange the staves.

Comment: More detail in my answer.  But you got a vote!

Answer (score 1):

The exchange of clefs is the smaller problem. Worse is the wrong representation of the rhythm in your version! the best way to correct bad midifiles is to play it in yourself by taking some useful information you got by this bad notation. this version is in dm but there are wrong enharmonics e.g.  Bb is enharmonic A# (as a result of the wrong key assignment), triplets are notated here as 6 eighth notes but the measure sign is given in as 3/4, while 6/8 would be correct.

You will learn much more if you correct this notation by playing it a new and better.

https://musescore.com/user/46224/scores/287776

Answer (score 0):

The clefs and left hand right hand switches throughout, that's how it appears in your example.

You could try this editing fix in Musescore. Add two new staffs below the existing staves. Add a new treble and bass. Cut and paste bars from the existing jumbled staves into the appropriate new staves. After all the music is copied into the right place in the new staves delete the original staves.

Save a backup file of the original before you start. Save as you work in the edit file frequently. Might be a good idea to save an additional back up of the edit file before deleting the staves. Sometimes big edits to the whole score don't do what you want and are hard to undo, so make backup files.

Answer (score -2):

Oh whow - that IS annoying.
First thing comes to mind is to save as a bmp or jpg file. Open in a paint or graphic program and just copy and paste the keys into the right position. I know it sounds kind of stupid, but it might be the quickest solution. (I use paint.net for doing similar things.)

Comment: If it's in musescore, edit with that not a 'photo-editing' program.